# Check firmware version of iPhones using Exchange?

Tags: exchange, iphone, firmware

I have about 20 users that use iphones that are connected to exchange. They have the device policy that says you have to have a lock code and 10 wrong passwords erases your phone, etc. I am using exchange 2010 and was wondering if there is a way that I can see what firmware/iOS version their phones are running? The `Get-MobileDevice` cmdlet was not introduced until exchange 2013 and right clicking on a user in EAC and then choosing `Manage Mobile Phones` only shows the last sync time and device name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Exchange Management Shell

```
Get-ActiveSyncDevice
```

Look At DeviceOS it will give the version